# Why has the icon for my website changed on its own?

Tags: lamp, hacking, linode

I installed the lamp stack on a Linode at the beginning of the year. It's just a personal website, accessed by IP address, so I doubt anyone else knows of it.

Recently the icon (next to the website's browser tab) has changed to this leaf. I have not made any changes to the website. How can the icon have changed like this? How can I find out of someone has hacked my site or not?

[image: Leaf Icon]

Comment: Check `example.com/favicon.ico` and see if it's this image, where `example.com` is your IP/domain.

Comment: Are you using Spring? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40494825/why-does-spring-boot-replace-all-of-my-favicons-with-springs-leaf-icon https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot/src/main/resources/favicon.ico

Comment: @ceejayoz I don't have a favicon.ico file ;{

Comment: I don't think I'm using Spring. I have Python and Apache installed. It's a very basic personal website. I expect the only user of the website to be myself and as far as I know it should not be listed anywhere

Comment: Can you share the website URL so we can take a look?